# Use kamailio dialplan module with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, kamailio

I'm trying to setup the kamailio dialplan module with mongodb as a backend. The configuration worked with mysql as a backend, and the other modules I use (subscriber, location) work fine with mongodb now.

The relevant config in kamailio.cfg:

```
#!define DBURL "mongodb://localhost/kamailio"
loadmodule "dialplan.so"
modparam("dialplan", "db_url", DBURL)
```

And in the main route I use:

```
if (dp_translate("100")) {
        xlog("dialplan: translation succeeded\n");
}
else {
        xlog("dialplan: translation failed\n");
}
```

In mongodb, I got:

```
> db.getCollection("version").find({"table_name":"dialplan"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589de6af3d305445959b19d9"), "table_name" : "dialplan", "table_version" : 2 }
> db.dialplan.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589dec2f3d305445959b19db"), "dpid" : 100, "pr" : 50, "match_op" : 1, "match_exp" : "^003$", "match_len" : 0, "subst_exp" : "^003$", "repl_exp" : "11111", "attrs" : "abc" }
```

But the module fails to apply this. For example:

```
$kamcmd dialplan.dump 100
error: 500 - Dialplan ID not matched
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some of the values should be ints (as specified in dialplan.json), which I didn't specify on insert. When I do:

```
  db.dialplan.insert( { "dpid" : NumberInt(100), "pr": NumberInt(1), "match_op" : NumberInt(1), "match_exp" : "^003$", "match_len" : NumberInt(0), "subst_exp" : "^003$", "repl_exp" : "11111", "attrs" : "abc" } )
```

Everything works fine:

```
$kamcmd dialplan.translate 100 s:003
{
    Output: 11111
    Attributes: abc
}
```